# Is it possible to separate one file among 4 files 3 rows at a time?

Tags: text-processing

The rub is that the original file may contain anywhere from 0 to 45 rows, but always divisible by 3.

I tried the `split -l` command but it creates too many files.  I was hoping for someone to point me in the right direction, and I do not think `split` is it.

Original File example w/ 15 rows:

```
lineAA|data|Format via FG|398
lineAB|data|Format via FG|398
lineAC|data|Format via FG|398
line_XA|data|Format via FG|398
line_XB|data|Format via FG|398
line_XC|data|Format via FG|398
line_ZA|data|Format via FG|398
line_ZB|data|Format via FG|398
line_ZC|data|Format via FG|398
line_XX|data|Format via FG|398
line_XY|data|Format via FG|398
line_XZ|data|Format via FG|398
line_FA|data|Format via FG|398
line_FB|data|Format via FG|398
line_FC|data|Format via FG|398
...
```

EXAMPLE OF OUTPUT:

FILE-1

```
    lineAA|data|Format via FG|398
    lineAB|data|Format via FG|398
    lineAC|data|Format via FG|398
    line_FA|data|Format via FG|398
    line_FB|data|Format via FG|398
    line_FC|data|Format via FG|398
```

FILE-2

```
    line_XA|data|Format via FG|398
    line_XB|data|Format via FG|398
    line_XC|data|Format via FG|398
```

FILE-3

```
    line_ZA|data|Format via FG|398
    line_ZB|data|Format via FG|398
    line_ZC|data|Format via FG|398
```

FILE-4

```
    line_XX|data|Format via FG|398
    line_XY|data|Format via FG|398
    line_XZ|data|Format via FG|398
```

Comment: You gave an example file but didn't say what you want to do with that file

Comment: what does mean your *one file **among** 4 files 3 rows at a time*? What should be the result for 6 lines?

Comment: I'm guessing lines 1-3 go to file A, lines 4-6 to file B, 7-9 to file C, 10-12 to D, 13-15 back to file A, etc. @Emile?

Comment: also, what is the naming convention for newly created files?

Comment: Look at `split`.

Comment: @BLayer You are correct!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the name will be STATUS_FILE-1.TXT, STATUS_FILE-2.TXT etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**awk** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ f=1 }!(NR%3){ n=NR+1 }NR==n{ f++ }
     { print > "STATUS_FILE-"f".txt" }!(NR%12){ f=0 }' file
```

- `BEGIN{ f=1 }` - set the initial file index number
- `!(NR%3)` - evaluates to `true` on each 3rd line
- `f++` - increment file index number after each 3rd line
- `!(NR%12){ f=0 }` - reset file index number after each 12th line(4th section)
- `print > "STATUS_FILE-"f".txt"` - print line into the file with needed file index number

---

Viewing results:

```
$ head STATUS_FILE*
==> STATUS_FILE-1.txt <==
lineAA|data|Format via FG|398
lineAB|data|Format via FG|398
lineAC|data|Format via FG|398
line_FA|data|Format via FG|398
line_FB|data|Format via FG|398
line_FC|data|Format via FG|398

==> STATUS_FILE-2.txt <==
line_XA|data|Format via FG|398
line_XB|data|Format via FG|398
line_XC|data|Format via FG|398

==> STATUS_FILE-3.txt <==
line_ZA|data|Format via FG|398
line_ZB|data|Format via FG|398
line_ZC|data|Format via FG|398

==> STATUS_FILE-4.txt <==
line_XX|data|Format via FG|398
line_XY|data|Format via FG|398
line_XZ|data|Format via FG|398
```

---

To create a "stand-alone" **awk** script:

**`split_on_4x3.awk`** script contents:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { f=1 }
!(NR%3) { n=NR+1 }
NR==n { f++ }
{ print > "STATUS_FILE-"f".txt" }
!(NR%12) { f=0 }
```

---

Usage:

```
awk -f split_on_4x3.awk inputfile
```

Comment: The script will be used by our scheduling tool Autosys to be run multiple times a day.  A second script is using the output files to start processes in Peoplesoft, timestamp, and archive these output files.  Out of curiosity how would this be written as a awk script?

Comment: @Emile, see my update

Answer (score 3):

This will write your file, in groups of three lines at a time, cyclically to each of `file0.txt`, `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`. I have split it over several lines but it can be combined as a single line simply by joining the lines together:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { f=-1 }
    !( (NR-1) % 3) { f = (f+1) % 4 }
    { print > "file" f ".txt" }
' source.txt
```

This `awk` program has three instructions. The `BEGIN {}` block is executed as the program starts, before the first line has been read. Each line of input is applied to the remaining two instructions. The first counts lines in groups of three (`NR` holds the current line number), and at the end of each group increments the file number, `f`. When the file number reaches the fourth item it's reset back to the first. (This count-and-reset approach uses the modulo operator, `%`.)

Comment: I'm receiving the following errors ``line 10: BEGIN: command not found  command substitution: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `%'   command substitution: line 11: ``     `!( (NR-1) % 3) { f = (f+1) % 4 }'`

Comment: @Emile how have you managed to get an error about a line 10? There are only three lines in the program! (You are copying and pasting just the code block, aren't you?)

Comment: I typed it out, but I found the resolution in the awk command above.  I'll try yours again when I have time to try and understand it, for now I'm just trying to get through this project with my sanity.    OH I KNOW WHY... I put the command in a script and I didn't start the script on line 1.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use `split`.  From its manual page:

> ```
> NAME
>      split -- split a file into pieces
>
> SYNOPSIS
>      split [-a suffix_length] [-b byte_count[k|m]] [-l line_count] [-p pattern] [file [name]]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>      The split utility reads the given file and breaks it up into files of 1000 lines each.  If
>      file is a single dash (`-') or absent, split reads from the standard input.
>
>      The options are as follows: [...]
>
>
>      -l line_count
>              Create smaller files n lines in length.
> ```

`split bigfile -l3` will split `bigfile` in to smaller files, each with three lines.

Comment: `split` is mentioned in the second sentence of the question and doesn't do what's required.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I need a max of 4 files that will be pre-named.  `split -l3` creates infinite files.

Comment: In fairness to myself, `split` was in fact _not_ mentioned in the question when I raised it as an answer.

Comment: It was in [revision 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/403167/1)...